# ORMlite creating more than one table ANDROID

Tags: android, ormlite

I understand the [ORMLite Android examples](http://ormlite.com/android/examples/). However, I have more than one class that I want to map with the ORMlite.

In the example to create the table which match with "SimpleData" class we used this :

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
    try {
        Log.i(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "onCreate");
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, SimpleData.class);
    } 

    catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "Can't create database", e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

How can I create all my tables (which matches my classes) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the same way you created the first one: with multiple calls of TableUtils.createTable method, to whom you'll pass the class representing the table in database

Answer (score 3):

So maybe I'm not understanding what you are trying to do.  In the `SimpleData` example above, you are quoting code from the `DatabaseHelper`.  In the `onCreate` method you can create any number of classes that you want:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
    try {
        Log.i(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "onCreate");
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, SimpleData.class);
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, AnotherData.class);
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, AndAnotherData.class);
        ...
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        ...
```

For a working program. if you take a look at the [ClickCounter example](http://ormlite.com/docs/android-examples), it creates two entities in its `onCreate` method:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
    try {
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, ClickGroup.class);
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, ClickCount.class);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "Unable to create datbases", e);
    }
}
```